# Issues after switching over to HTTPS

Tags: https, plugin-contact-form-7

I've just added SSL on my site and a questionnaire I have running isn't formatting correctly on the HTTPS. This is being driven by Contact Form 7 plugin. It still works fine on the HTTP site.

Edit: I've tried using the Really Simple SSL & SSL Insecure Content Fixer plugins with no lucky

Weirdly, it is working correctly when I am logged into my Wordpress Admin account and I access the HTTPS version.

It doesn't seem to be a mixed content issue.

[Working version](http://aus-finance.com.au/refinance2) (HTTP & when logged into WP):

[image: Working version]

[Broken Version](https://aus-finance.com.au/refinance2) (HTTPS version):

[image: Broken Version]

Comment: URL please so we can see it happening?

Comment: http://aus-finance.com.au/refinance2 & https://aus-finance.com.au/refinance2

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cache?
In the second link, there are a lot of inline css and js files that doesn't get loaded in the page. I suspect that those are responsible for the styling and the functionality of the "buttons". Namely `http://aus-finance.com.au/wp-content/themes/ausfinance/js/qform.js?ver=1.0`.

Comment: disable your cache plugin wp fastest cache and delete your cache folder.

Comment: What kind of caching plugin needs this drastic steps to delete the cache for a single page?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved similar problems by running a [search and replace plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/). That way you can query the database and make it change all the http:// entries to https://.

Answer (score -1):

Getting rid of the caching software was the answer. Thanks everyone for your help.